# How to generate .NET 4 Dump files

Tags: .net

I wanted to know if there is a possibility to dump all stack variable when an exception occurs in .NET 4 so I can analyze it later (in production serveR)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some resources around.

See [Writing Minidumps in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dondu/writing-minidumps-in-c). Minidumps later can be analyzed either in WinDbg or in VS 2010.

You may also interested in [Is it impossible to show forms when handling a AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001486/is-it-impossible-to-show-forms-when-handling-a-appdomain-currentdomain-unhandlede) and [What is the best way to collect crash data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366718/what-is-the-best-way-to-collect-crash-data)

Answer (score 1):

The [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class is intended to do this.

You can also gather important information like the source file, position, running thread, the method in which the crash occured etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the windows event log, usually exceptions are logged there with all the details you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

[windbg](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx) can do this.

See details on [this blog](http://mcfunley.com/102/managed-debugging-with-windbg-part-1-of-n).